# Type not being checked in custom response structure in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am starting of with typescript and have hit a roadblock where I can't figure out why types are not being validated.

**Route**

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // here 404 is a string but should be a number according to type defined but no error is shown
  return res.error({ status: '404', message: 'The API route does not exist' })
})
```

**Middleware**

```
interface APIResponse {
  status: number,
  message?: string | null,
  data?: any
}

const responseHelper = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.showDefaultErrorPage = (status: number = 500) => {
      //...
  }

  res.success = (options: APIResponse) => {
    const {
      status = 200,
      message = null,
      data
    } = options

    //...
  }

  res.error = (options: APIResponse) => {
    const {
      status = 500,
      message = null
    } = options

    //...
  }

  next()
}

export default responseHelper
```

**Custom type definition for express response**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
declare namespace Express {
  interface Response {
    showDefaultErrorPage?: any
    showErrorPage?: any
    success?: any
    error?: any
  }
}
```

Comment: Well it looks like you gave `error` the type `any`. So no validation takes place. Why don't you give it the correct type?

Comment: Am not sure what to set, as error is a function and that function and that function takes in an object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your type definiton to this:

```
import express from "express" 
const app = express()


interface APIResponse {
  status: number,
  message?: string | null,
  data?: any
}

// add "declare global" here
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Response<
      ResBody = any,
      Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
      StatusCode extends number = number
    > {
      showDefaultErrorPage?: any
      showErrorPage?: any
      success: (options: APIResponse) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
      error: (options: APIResponse) => Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>
    }
  }
}

// Dont give explicit types here. Let TypeScript infer them
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  res.showDefaultErrorPage = (status: number = 500) => {
      //...
  }

  res.success = (options: APIResponse) => {
    const {
      status = 200,
      message = null,
      data
    } = options

    return res.status(0).json({})
  }

  res.error = (options: APIResponse) => {
    const {
      status = 500,
      message = null
    } = options

    return res.status(0).json({})
  }

  next()
})

// Dont give explicit types here 
app.use((req, res) => {
  return res.error({ status: '404', message: 'The API route does not exist' })
  //                 ^^^^^^ Expected error
})
```

Comment: Returning:
 return res.status(status).json({
      status,
      message: message || getStatusMessage(status) || 'Server error'
    })

Comment: So the ApiResponse interface must go in the custom type definiton file, and get removed from middleware file?

Comment: @Ayan - Well you are gonna need this interface in both files. So you may export it and import it in the other file.

Comment: Could you please help me understand why would I need in both places?

Comment: @Ayan - You need in the `declare namespace Express { ...` for the type of the argument in the function but also in the `responseHelper` because you are using it as the type of the argument of `res.success` too.

Comment: ooh! I understand. BTW, I get the following: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)` on res.error also on res.success

Comment: @Ayan - Yes, you specified that `success` and `error` are optional, so a `Response` might or might not have them. You would either need to check if they are defined before calling them, or remove the question mark.

Comment: Got it. Getting to understand how it works. One last thing, `Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>` does this mimic the ApiInterface once again?

Comment: @Ayan - I just checked what type `res.status(status).json` returns as this is also the return type of your function if you just return its result.

Comment: The app crashes with the error: `TS2551: Property 'error' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'. Did you mean 'errored'?`

Is it because error function is being set in a middleware?

Comment: @Ayan - On which line does this error happen?

Comment: The error is thrown when I run the app. This error happens wherever I have used the custom functions `error`, `success` etc.

Comment: @Ayan - That does not look like a runtime error. That error is definitely produced by TypeScript during compile time. How are you compiling the app? Just `tsc` or something with `webpack`?

Comment: nodemon for the dev, tsc for build.

Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247623/discussion-between-ayan-and-tobias-s).